# Should I use git submodules in go project?

Tags: git, go, git-submodules

There's a project written in go language. And it's managed using git. Should I use git submodules or just import directives to use a 3rd-party project?

For example:

```
// Just use import directive.
import "github.com/3rd-party/dep"

// From a submodule.
$ cd myown
$ git add submodule https://github.com/3rd-party/dep dep
$ ...
import "github.com/myown/dep"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `import "github.com/3rd-party/dep"`
and then run `go get` in the working directory

Answer (score -3):

Just import directive.
Git submodules has a bad rep.